# JSON data not showing in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When Click the book now button then it's going to a Booking page.

Here Image and Seat availability data from JSON not showing. And also when I submit the form cannot reset after the alert box comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your codesandbox app to make it work as you expect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/event-booking-app-5dyw0

Comment: Thank you very much.